# Prevent Parent page from reloading when exit button is clicked in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a popup using modal. When user clicks on a link it will show this modal popup. I have put an exit button inside popup in order to close the popup. My problem is when i click on the exit button, the popups exits but the parent page gets reloaded.

Is there any way to preventing the parent page from reloading.

Here is the code for modal popup:

```
<div id="box-config-modal1" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
  <div class="box" id="box-details">
    <h4 class="box-header round-top">Details</h4>

    <div class="box-container-toggle" style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">
      <div class="box-content">
        <form name="popup" id="popup">
          <fieldset>

            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            <h3>User Details</h3>

            <div class="control-group">

              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">Name </label><label id="advname" style="padding-left:150px;"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">

              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">ID </label><label id="advid" style="padding-left:150px;"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">

              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">Email </label><label id="email1" style="padding-left:150px;"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">

              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">Country </label><label id="country" style="padding-left:150px;"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">

              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">Website </label><label id="website" style="padding-left:150px;"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls" id="newlist">
                <label class="control-label" for="typeahead" style="width:100px;float:left;">Change
                  History </label><label id="changehistory" style="padding-left:150px;"></label></div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to return false in your onClick, it will prevent from reload the page because the default type for a button in a form is 'submit'

Answer (score 2):

Since your `<form>` doesn't have any submit button, so browser treating that button as submit button.

So use this code

```
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:return false;"></button>
```

**OR put this button outside `<form>` Tag**

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are using bootstrap modal.

You can create custom button to close bootstrap modal. Just check the following code

`<a href="#" class="my-close-btn">Close Popup</a>`

```
$(function () {
    $(".my-close-btn").on('click', function() {
        $('#box-config-modal1').modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried as u said. Created custom button to close bootstrap modal. But its not working. It didn't even close the modal..

Comment: @Aishwaryas: can you create a jsfiddle for your modal ?

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle.. As am a beginner in js and haven't used jsfiddle ever before, Please dont mind if any mistakes.. Here is the link:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/aishwaryas/cbf12n99/)

Comment: @Aishwaryas: I was asking you to create a working example of your modal. Anyway its fine. I have just created a fiddle with a modal popup with custom close button. [pls check](http://jsfiddle.net/nauphaltf/w1rLpoaj/)